# Different Log File For Specific Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I currently have a controller were I would like to keep track of logging in a separate log file, like: tracker.log. I currently get about 100,000 hits a day with this, and I would like to separate the log from all the other controllers so I can easily debug those as well as the tracker.
I couldn't find anything for the Rails::Initializer, that would extend specifically for a controller.
I know it will be something along the lines of:

```
config.log_path = 'log/tracker.log'
```

Although you can't re-run the Rails initializer mid load, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create your own instance of the Logger class (which is used by Rails to generate log files) and pass it a File instance as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK rails can't maintain two separate log file simultaneously.  I'd recommend doing your own logging in the controller in question.

In similar situations I've used [log4r](http://log4r.sourceforge.net/).  It's very [easy](http://log4r.sourceforge.net/manual.html#outofbox) to get started.